# can't push to heroku

Tags: django, git, heroku

I'm doing the getting stared with django tutorial and when I run the command "git push heroku master" this happens

```
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 2.14 KiB, done.
Total 11 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Python app detected
-----> No runtime.txt provided; assuming python-2.7.6.
-----> Preparing Python runtime (python-2.7.6)
-----> Installing Setuptools (2.1)
-----> Installing Pip (1.5.4)
-----> Installing dependencies using Pip (1.5.4)
   Downloading/unpacking Django==1.6.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
   Downloading/unpacking argparse==1.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
     Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_u33537/argparse/setup.py) egg_info for package argparse

       no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/_build'
       no previously-included directories found matching 'env24'
       no previously-included directories found matching 'env25'
       no previously-included directories found matching 'env26'
       no previously-included directories found matching 'env27'
   Downloading/unpacking distribute==0.6.24 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
     Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_u33537/distribute/setup.py) egg_info for package distribute

       warning: no files found matching 'Makefile' under directory 'docs'
       warning: no files found matching 'indexsidebar.html' under directory 'docs'
   Installing collected packages: Django, argparse, distribute
     Running setup.py install for argparse

       no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/_build'
       no previously-included directories found matching 'env24'
       no previously-included directories found matching 'env25'
       no previously-included directories found matching 'env26'
       no previously-included directories found matching 'env27'
     Running setup.py install for distribute
       Before install bootstrap.
       Scanning installed packages
       Setuptools installation detected at /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.1-py2.7.egg
       Egg installation
       Patching...
       Renaming /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.1-py2.7.egg into /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.1-py2.7.egg.OLD.1400612619.61
       Patched done.
       Relaunching...
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
       NameError: name 'install' is not defined
       Complete output from command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_u33537/distribute/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-wPuSVj-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
       Before install bootstrap.

   Scanning installed packages

   Setuptools installation detected at /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.1-py2.7.egg

   Egg installation

   Patching...

   Renaming /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.1-py2.7.egg into /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.1-py2.7.egg.OLD.1400612619.61

   Patched done.

   Relaunching...

   Traceback (most recent call last):

     File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

   NameError: name 'install' is not defined

   ----------------------------------------
   Cleaning up...
   Command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_u33537/distribute/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-wPuSVj-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_u33537/distribute
   Storing debug log for failure in /app/.pip/pip.log

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app

 To git@heroku.com:sheltered-citadel-7550.git
  ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
  error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:sheltered-citadel-7550.git'
```

Here is my Procfile

```
web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload
```

Here's my requirements.txt file

```
Django==1.6.5
argparse==1.2.1
setuptools==0.7.3
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

I've been searching stack over flow for a while and I've fond many similar problems, but none of the solutions have worked for me yet any help with be appreciated.

Comment: I think only Django must be in the requirements file, no?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the root of the problem but it looks like django-toolbelt is not installed or your requirements.txt didn't include everything. See here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django

Delete requirements.txt, then:

```
pip install django-toolbelt
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

At a minimum, requirements.txt should have (with different versions):

```
Django==1.6
dj-database-url==0.2.2
dj-static==0.0.5
gunicorn==18.0
psycopg2==2.5.1
static==0.4
wsgiref==0.1.2
```